# How to use raw sockets in WinCE5?

Tags: windows-ce, winsock, raw-sockets

I need to use raw sockets in Windows CE 5.0. The following code always fails with error

`socket failed, err:10044`.
(The support for the specified socket type does not exist in this address family.)

```
WSAData wsaData;
SOCKET s;
int n;

n = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData);

if (n < 0) {
  printf("WSAStartUp failed, err:%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
} else {
  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);

  if (s < 0)
  {
    printf("socket failed, err:%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
  }
}
```

What must I do for using raw sockets in Windows CE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw IP sockets are not supported in Windows CE 5.0.
You can use NDISUIO to send packets with arbitrary content.

Answer (score 0):

I find MSDN documentations for WinCE specific sockets are rather few, but the [guide for desktop winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740632.aspx) is pretty nice.

I stumbled upon the following links when trying to write my very first socket app for WinCE 5.0:

- [Porting Socket Applications to Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740096.aspx)
- [Porting Raw Socket to Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740463.aspx)
- [Determining if Raw Sockets are supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548.aspx)

I hope you find them useful.

Note that even though the above articles are for desktop, I can use the concepts and codes with few modifications.

Comment: Your answer unfortunately doesn't address windows CE. I've learned that raw IP sockets are not supported. You can use NDISUIO instead.

Comment: Then you may want to add a proper answer to the question to help others if you now know the answer (I may delete my answer if too many people down vote and your comment will also get deleted).